# extracting first two digits of a number haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm getting a frustrating error when I try to extract the first two digits of a number. First, I work out the length of digit using log, then I divide the number by the `10^(length of digit - 2)` to extract the first two digits. The len and divisor functions work fine, but the firstTwo function fails, and I don't understand this because it seems so straight forward. I even tried adding `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}`, but nothing.  Please assist. Here's the code:

```
len n = (+) 1 $ truncate $ logBase 10 n -- length of a digit

divisor n = 10 ^ (len n - 2)

firstTwo n = div n divisor
```

The error I get is:

Non type-variable argument in the constraint: `Integral (r -> a)`

```
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
When checking that ‘firstTwo’ has the inferred type
  firstTwo :: forall a r.
              (Floating r, Integral (r -> a), Num a, RealFrac r) =>
              (r -> a) -> r -> a
```

Comment: Try adding type signatures to get a better error.

Comment: You also need to check that the exponent is not negative. In other word make sure your number is at least of 2 digit.

Answer (score 3):

You use `div` on `n` and `divisor`, but `divisor` isn't the same type as `n`, it's a function. That's why you end up with `Integral (r -> a)`.

Use `firstTwo n = div n (divisor n)`, but keep in mind that `logBase` only works on `Floating` such as `Double` and `Float`, whereas `div` only works on `Integral` such as `Integer` and `Int`. Therefore, it will still not compile, unless you've changed `len`'s type.

Add type signatures to your function to get better error messages.

Comment: Thank you very much Zeta. I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to be a beginner my very first advice would be, to add type information as much as possible. At least for every top level (function) definition. This helps you, the compiler and everyone else reading your code understanding ​your intent.

Now to your problem: you try to divide a number `n` by a function `divisor`

```
div n (divisor n)
```

Should do the trick, well there is one small bit missing - `logBase` does not work on integers, while `div` does only work on integers. So you need to call `fromInteger` first to convert.

An alternative that would work with a small adjustment for negative numbers could be `take 2 . show`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your number to String.
2. Check if the string contains 2 or more chars.
3. If the check is successful, take first 2 chars from your string and convert them to Int (or put those chars in tuple or do with them whatever you want).
4. Do something with the case if your number contains less than 2 digits (throw error for example).

   ```
   firstTwo :: Integer -> Int
   firstTwo n
     | (length . show $ n) >= 2 = read . take 2 . show $ n
     | otherwise = error "The number contains less than 2 digits"
   ```